# Run script on Hyper-V vm's guest OS wiithout network connectiontt

Tags: shell, hyper-v

I'm looking for a method to run a shell(PowerShell and bash) script on my Hyper-V virtual machines. A specific requirement is that those machines are not connected to any network, so i can't use, for example, a remote PowerShell connection. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Not an immediate answer, but when Windows Server 2016 ships, its Hyper-V includes a thing called "PowerShell Direct" that'll let you run cmdlets on the host that run on the VMs even if there's no network.

Comment: As I can understand from [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/virtualization/archive/2015/05/14/powershell-direct-running-powershell-inside-a-virtual-machine-from-the-hyper-v-host.aspx) post, this feature (PowerShell direct) requires the guest OS to be Windows 10.

Comment: True, but 2016's not out yet so we can't say what the ultimate result will be.  Certainly 2016 has more "... and will work with downlevel" features than before.  Fingers crossed!